# How to generate an auto increment ID number with date and resets the next day in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpmyadmin, yii2

I'm having a hard time figuring out on how to make a sequential number on my ID field together with the date today and then resets the next day with the date of the next day.

For example:

```
+------------+------+
| id         | name |
+------------+------+
| 0322150001 | John |
| 0322150002 | Mark |
| 0322150003 | Josh |
| 0323150001 | Paul |
| 0323150002 | Bon  |
+------------+------+
```

Comment: sorry for the example , here is the correct image

http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y475/plansigan/example_zpsaa032ds9.png

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? It makes no sense, you don't use auto_increment field for such purposes. Research about triggers, stored procedures and events in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that value to be implicitly set when inserting a row (i.e. without mentioning `id` in your query), the only way I know of is to set a default value for that field.
Quoting the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; **it cannot be a function or an expression.** [...] The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns.

So your options are limited to either using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and setting the field type to `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`, or you set the `id` field in your SQL query.